# My TEC1-12710 peltier cell not cooling enough

Tags: power-supply, amperage, peltier

I have a TEC1-12710 Peltier cell which supposedly consumes 10 Amps but when I connected to the power supply (12-15 Vdc 15Amp 180 Watt) the cell only used 4-5 Amp and didn't give me good cooling

the Cold side with sink is 15 degree C, and the hot side with sink and fan is 45 C degree and the Ambient temperature is 24-25 degree C.

I am confused on why the cold sink is not freezing as I saw in some YouTube videos!

do I need to use a PS with more Amperage to get more cold?

The hot side is not bad since the temperature of Hot sink does not exceed 45 C degree, AM I right? or need to be less!

I am feeding 12Vdc for Peltier

Thanks for all and I hope you will be able to help me

Comment: Hi welcome to EE sx, even with a simple circuit as this it's always nice to provide a circuit drawing, which you can embed when editing your questions, and please provide the voltage on the cell

Comment: I edited the question and mentioned the Voltage on the cell. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a difference between the two sides of 30 C, which is pretty typical for peltiers.

You need to cool the hot side better.

You can also try limiting the current, because a bunch of that heat you are seeing is being generated by the peltier itself.  You have to keep in mind how inefficient they are (they create several watts of heat for every watt they move).

Comment: thank you for your solution! but if the different is around 30 C, so I think is good and I have to see Ice!..and How can I limit the current the real current which peltier consume it is 3.5 Amp only..How can i increase it...my PS is 15 A 180 W

Comment: I increase the Voltage to 15 V dc, the peltier consume 4.5 A but the same cooling result no difference!

Comment: You could decrease the current with a resistor or just lowering the voltage if you have an adjustable supply.  It is unlikely that increasing the current will lead to more cooling, in fact, you will eventually end up heating the cold side!  Your best bet is going to be cooling the hot side further.

Comment: The important part of my answer is pointing out that for every watt of heat the peltier moves it creates several more.  Since the hot and cold sides are physically connected, this extra heat bleeds over to the cold side and increases the amount of work the peltier needs to accomplish.  Very soon it cannot keep up and cannot move as much heat as is being created on the cold side.

Comment: Also, note that when I say a difference of 30 C, that is between the two sides of the peltier, not cold side to ambient.

Comment: yes I got it now your point! I lowered now the voltage to 10 v and I will monitor the result how it will be. about 30 C yes I got your point is the delta T between two sides. So What I understand now, less Current more cold! and more current will increase the hot production in the hot side! Am I right?

Comment: I lowered the Voltage to be 10.86 v and the cold side get down from 15.5 to 12 C degree! but still not lower more! to give Ice

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly.  Find a way to remove more heat from the hot side, or reduce the load on the cold side (smaller heat sink).

Comment: I am thinking to add Aluminium Block (Cube) above cold side then I put the cold sink which will  help to Isolate the cold side from the Hot side..Is it good Idea?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, you cannot isolate the cold side form the hot side as they are directly connected together.  Anything to reduce the area the cold side is cooling or increase the amount of heat removed from the hot side will help.

Comment: I mean like put this Aluminium Block above cold side then mount the sink above the block..

Comment: Just update..I replaced tec1-12710 with tec1-12706 and I adjust the voltage to 10 vdc then the cold side is around 6 C degree!

Comment: You are getting closer.  You actually want to reduce the size of the cold side because you can only remove so many watts per second.  The smaller the area the better.